# Add-In Model for .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, add-in

It is possible to use [Add-In Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/add-ins/) in .Net Framework 4.7.1 (the `System.AddIn.dll` and `System.AddIn.Contract.dll` assemblies). But I didn't find these assemblies in .Net Core 2.1 (I searched in NuGet Packages).

Does it mean Add-In Model will not be ported to .Net Core? Which is alternative exist and work for .Net Framework and .Net Core both?

Comment: Its not yet available for .Net Core

Comment: try if you can achive the same using MEF

Comment: @VilsadPP I looked this MEF example: https://dotnetthoughts.net/using-mef-in-dotnet-core/ Can MEF to load the plugin assembly into separate AppDomain?

Comment: I am not sure, but think its possible